# Возможно у сайта на php заменить главную на html?

Tags: php, html, замена

Пожалуйста, подскажите: Есть ли возможность у сайта, написанного на php - заменить главную на страницу, написанную на html, оставив все внутренние как есть?

Сайт: homeclimat36.ru

Comment: да, можно. сильно зависит от того, как внутренности устроены. Можно, например, сделать в .htaccess явный редирект